# how to retrieve hyperlinks in spreadsheet cells using gspread?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am not able to retrieve hyperlinks in google spreadsheet cells using gspread. I am always returned the text of the cell and not the hyperlink itself.

I have attempted

```
worksheet.cell(i, j, value_render_option="FORMULA")
```

with all the three possible options for `value_render_option` and none of them works.

I have seen some old answers here about using `input_value`, that unfortunately is not supported anymore

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? Because the the hyperlink might not be the formula. Of course, please remove your personal information. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cell content is something like

`=HYPERLINK("http://www.wikipedia.de","wikipedia")`

try

`cell = worksheet.cell(i, j, value_render_option='FORMULA').value`

Comment: Glad to hear! If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it.

Comment: This does not work anymore :( Any ideas why so?
TypeError: cell() got an unexpected keyword argument 'value_render_option'`

Comment: This works well outside a function but when I use the same code in a function, it prints only the link text, not the hyperlink. May someone know why?